# How to skip to new line while writing to CSV using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, export-to-csv

I have an array of objects say `array=[hello, how, are, you]` which I have extracted from **document.innerHTML.** I need to write them to a *CSV file using puppeteer and JavaScript* **one below the other.**
If I use the normal **fs.writeFile(), it gets printed like,**

```
hello how are you
```

But, **I want it to be written in the file one below the other** like,

```
hello
how
are
you
```

How do I possibly achieve this?
How do I go to a new line after each entry?

**NOTE:**

1)Please note that this is an array of **OBJECTS** and not **STRINGS.**

2)It is fine if I change the array to string and then write into the file.

Here's the code that I've written so far.

```
for(var k=0; k<value.length; k++){
  data=value[k]
  fs.writeFile('export1.csv', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been saved!');
    
  });
```

**EXTRA CREDITS:**

Is there any way I can stop writing in the same column and move to a new column? And switch back over?

Comment: For future reference, strings are objects (they are instances of the `String` class).

Comment: Can you clarify how you want to have the object to the file? Are you wanting to write the object as JSON? Is there a specific field of the object you want to use?

Comment: @Moutah I just want to write the array of texts into CSV. That alone will do. Type really doesn't matter.

Comment: But you say you have an array of objects. Can you give more details on those objects or an example of the array? I'm not understanding your situation properly.

Comment: Try using this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/objects-to-csv ..   I suppose this is what you are looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Given your description, I believe the below is what you are looking for:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const array = [
    {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    },
    {
      c: 3,
      d: 4
    }
];

const dataToSave = array.map(item => {
    return JSON.stringify(item)
      .replace(/\"/gi, '""');
  })
  .map(item => `"${item}"`)
  .join('\n');

fs.writeFile('export1.csv', dataToSave, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been saved!');    
});
```

Working with CSVs and objects is a little complicated because both CSVs and JSON strings use quotes and commas to deliminate things. In the above the objects in the array are JSON stringified, then the quotes `"` are escaped as `""`. Additionally, the array items are then enclosed in quotes `"` and finally joined with a new line escaped character `\n`.

If you're on a window's machine you may want to do `\r` instead of `\n`. Whatever you're using to open the .csv, like Excel, should be smart enough to figure out the line ending regardless if it is `\n` or `\r`.

For the extra credit, use a comma (`,`) to move to another column. CSV stands for "comma separated value," so the comma is is the delimiter to separate the text into discrete parts, each of which displays in a separate column. For example, you can replace:

```
.map(item => `"${item}"`)
```

with:

```
.map(item => `,"${item}"`) // Comma added here
```

If you want to do anything more complicated than this, I would look into:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv

References:

- Array `.map()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- String `.replace()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
- `JSON.stringify()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify
- New line character `\n`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline